# ASP.net Configuration Error- allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, windows-authentication

I uploaded my webapplication using FTP to a space. I am getting this error. I have created the virtual directory and configured it in IIS.I am getting this error.

Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
Line 52:             ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
Line 53:         -->
Line 54:        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
Line 55:        
Line 56:             <!--The <customErrors> section enables configuration
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a virtual directory which is not an application.
In IIS, Right click on it and `Convert To Application`